# Use MVC 3 ViewBag to dynamically change an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to MVC 3 and still learning. I'm currently building a static 2 page website which has a different image on both pages but are located in the same place. I have been told that I can use the ViewBag to change this image depending on what page I am on, however I have not got a clue where to begin with applying this to my website.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You for your time.

Comment: Can you post your views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your controller's Action method,make ViewBag or ViewData like this

```
ViewBag.Imagename="nameofimage";

ViewData["img"]="nameofimage";
```

On your view, you can make img  tag like this

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Imagename">
```

or if you have created ViewData

```
<img src="@ViewData["img"]">
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, it did **not** work for me when I simply tried using

```
@ViewBag.BackgroundImage = "~/Content/images/image.jpg"
...
<img src="@ViewBag.BackgroundImage" />
```

But what **did** work for me was

```
@ViewBag.BackgroundImage = "image.jpg"
...
<img src = "~/Content/images/@(ViewBag.BackgroundImage)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

personally i dont like specifying anything view related in controller, i am using naming convention between action method names and images:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower())_img.jpg">
```

and picture name for index action method would be "index_img.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

For those who want use full path in viewbag, use this

```
@ViewBag.BackgroundImage = "Content/images/image.jpg"
...
<img src="~/@ViewBag.BackgroundImage" />
```

The reason why hallordylo example not working with full path is missing `"~/"` in `src="..."` and this sign `"~/"` should not be inside ViewBag.