# Display image dynamically with ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display and change a image dynamically in the same view.
So I have tried to use the code: [Use MVC 3 ViewBag to dynamically change an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213182/use-mvc-3-viewbag-to-dynamically-change-an-image)

and this: [Pass image from controller and display in a view using ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142526/pass-image-from-controller-and-display-in-a-view-using-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

but didn't work.

Here is my `Index.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("showFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.TextBox("ImageID")
    <input type="submit" value="ok" class="submit" />
}

<img src="@ViewBag.Foto" alt="IMAGES" />
```

My `HomeController.cs`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult showFile(string ImageID)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/images/profile");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, ImageID + ".jpg");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        ViewBag.Foto = path.ToString();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use MVC 3 ViewBag to dynamically change an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213182/use-mvc-3-viewbag-to-dynamically-change-an-image) try a google search if all else fails

Comment: Take a look at the rendered HTML and make sure it is correct. For example: `<img src="/images/profile/id.jpg" alt="" />` Also check the image exists in the location src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are 2 issues with the code sample you have provided.

The **first** issue is that you are providing a full path to the image tag.  You are setting the ViewBag.Foto property with the contents of `Server.MapPath()` combined with the image so the resulting `img` tag will look similar to:

```
<img src="C:\your-local-path-here\images\profiles\image.jpg" alt="IMAGES"/>
```

But what you actually want is something similar to:

```
<img src="/images/profile/image.jpg" alt="IMAGES"/>
```

The **second** issue is that you are setting the `ViewBag` property with the image path and then performing a redirect.  When you return a redirect to the browser the content of `ViewBag` is not maintained for the next request to the `Index()` action.

The controller code could therefore be changed to:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult ShowFile(string imageId)
{
    var virtualPath = string.Format("~/images/profile/{0}.jpg", imageId);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(virtualPath)))
    {
        ViewBag.Foto = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(virtualPath);
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

Additionally, you do not need to specify `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }` in your form (see [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)).

Comment: You are right!! Should be "return View("Index");"!! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because Server.MapPath will return the physical path to the image, which is not what you want. You will want the server-relative path (/images/profile/xxxxx).

Comment: do you mean this? >> In controller:  ViewBag.Foto = "~/images/profile/"+ImageID+".jpg";

Comment: there is my new code: [my controller](http://pastie.org/9754989), [my view](http://pastie.org/9754990) Tempdata was Displayed "ok"...

Answer (score 1):

I would use "ViewBag.Foto" instead of "@ViewBag.Foto".

The @ sign would be used by razor syntax in a view, but not in a controller.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault... but the code original is "ViewBag.Foto = path.ToString();"